# Pass a lambda parameter to an include statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using the `System.Data.Entity` namespace, so I can pass lambda expressions to the Linq Include method.

```
public ICollection<MyEntity> FindAll()
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyEntityContext())
        {
            return ctx.MyEntity.Include(x => x.SomeLazyLoadedValue).ToList();
        }
    }
```

When I'm using a Where statement in a different method, I can pass a parameter to it like so:

```
public ICollection<MyEntity> FindAllBy(Func<MyEntity, bool> criteria)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyEntityContext())
        {
            return ctx.MyEntity.Where(criteria).ToList();
        }
    }
```

However, trying the same thing in an Include does not work:

```
public ICollection<MyEntity> FindAll(Func<MyEntity, bool> criteria)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyEntityContext())
        {
            return ctx.MyEntity.Include(criteria).ToList();
        }
    }
```

If you try this, Visual Studio will complain that it

```
Cannot convert from 'System.Func<MyEntity, bool>' to 'string'
```

How do I pass a lambda to the Include method?

Comment: Because the [`Include()` extension method you intend to invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) accepts an `Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path`, not a `Func<T, bool>`.

Comment: @CodeCaster is correct. The error you are seeing is because the `Include()` extension method has an overload accepting `string`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. For instance, your `FindAllBy` does not do a sql `WHERE` query, instead it loads all the entries in your database, and then filter in-memory based on your `criteria`. To understand why this is like so take a look at the following:

```
int a = 5;
long b = 5;
```

Now, it's quite obvious what's happening here, but it's still quite important. The compiler reads the following code and produces two variables. One integer and one long integer, both with values set to the number 5. However, the values of these two numbers are different, even though they are set (in the source code) to the same thing. One is 32-bit, and the other is 64-bit.

Now, let's take a look at the following code:

```
Func<int, string> a = num => num.ToString();
Expr<Func<int, string>> b = num => num.ToString();
```

Here the same thing (more or less) is happening. In the first case, the C# compiler sees you want a predicate (a `Func<int, string>` predicate), whereas the second value is a `Expr<Func<int, string>>` even though the values are written the same. However, as opposed to the first example, the end result here is vastly different.

A predicate is compiled as a method on a compiler-generated class. It's compiled just as any other code, and simply allows you to remove a bunch of boilerplate. A expression on the other hand is a in-memory representation of the actual code written. In this case, for instance, the expression might look something akin to `Call(int.ToString, $1)`. This can be read by other code and translated to for instance SQL which is then used to query your database.

Now, back to your problem. EntityFramework hands you `IQueryable<T>` instances, which in turn inherit `IEnumerable<T>`. Whenever you enumerate over the enumerable, it queries the database.

All the extension-methods that accept delegates are defined on `IEnumerable` and thus query your database **before** running the predicate. This is why you need to make sure to select the right method-overloads.

**Edit (to answer comment)]**
To clarify a bit more I'm going to make a few examples. Say for instance that we have a `User` class that cointains `FirstName`, `LastName` and `Age`, and the db collection is simply called `db`.

```
Expr<Func<User, bool>> olderThan10 = u => u.Age > 10;
Func<User, bool> youngerThan90 = u => u.Age < 90;
var users = db.Where(olderThan10).Where(youngerThan90);
```

This would result in SQL that finds all users that are older than 10, after which it would in-memory filter away everyone that was older than or equal to 90.

So passing a `Func` doesn't necessarily mean it queries the whole database. It just means it stops building on the query at that point, and executes it.

As for the next question, `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` is not a universal answer. It means "a expression that takes a T and returns a bool". In some cases, like `.Include` which started this whole question, you don't want to return a bool. You want to return whatever you want to include. So for instance, if we go back to our example of users, and amend a `Father` property on the user class which references another user, and we want to include it, in regular code we'd do

```
db.Include(u => u.Father);
```

Now. Here, `u` is a User, and the return value `u.Father` is also a user, so in this case `u => u.Father` is `Expr<Func<User, User>>` or `Expr<Func<User, object>>` (I don't know if entity-framework `.Include` accepts generic values or simply `object`s).

So your `FindAll` function should probably look like this:

```
public ICollection<TData> FindAll<TInclude>(Expr<Func<TData, TInclude>> include) {
    using (var ctx = new TContext()) {
        return ctx.T.Include(include).ToList();
    }
}
```

Though, to be honest, this is pretty weird looking code, and it's likely that you're doing something else weird with your models given that you've (for instance) named them `T` and `TContext`. My guess is that you need to read up a bit on how generics works in C#.

Comment: Thanks, that was a very interesting read. To make sure I understand correctly: using System.Data.Entity added extra overloads to all my Linq methods to accept Expression<Func<T,bool>> as well. However, that causes all methods where I pass a Func instead of an Expression to query the whole database before filtering the returned data. The solution is to alter all methods to work with Expression<Func<T, bool>>, correct?

Comment: @ohyeah - You can't pass a `Func` to those methods - you can only pass `Expression<Func<>>`.

Comment: Aaaaah. So in my source code it looks like I'm passing a Func, but the compiler handles it like an Expression, which causes inefficient querying. Correct? If so, how would I solve this?

Comment: @ohyeah I've appended my answer to clarify a bit and answer your comment.

Comment: @ohyeah - The compiler does its magic and handles it like an `Expression<>`, but I don't know why you're saying that causes **inefficient** querying - it's quite the opposite.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have also edited the usage of T in my question to MyEntity, so it's more clear. I am not doing any weird generics in this code.

Comment: @Alxandr, I wonder, how would you pass multiple Include statements?

Comment: You'd use a params array, just like any other C# method.

Comment: @Alxandr  I also wonder how can I write an extension method which accepts an array of delegates and perform the inculde for all of them. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63565729/5852947)

Comment: This is one of the best answers I have ever read on SO - thank you

Comment: What about passing `Include(u => u.Father)` as the parameter? That way you could chain several `Include()`s together if you need to also include say u.Mother?